# Installing Scrapy on Python VirtualEnv

Tags: python, scrapy, virtualenv

Here's my problem,
I have a shared hosting (GoDaddy Linux Hosting package) account and I'd like to create .py file to do some scraping for me. To do this I need the scrapy module (scrapy.org). Because of the shared account I can't install new modules so I installed VirtualEnv and created a new virtual env. that has pip, wheel, etc. preinstalled.

Running `pip install scrapy`does NOT complete successfully because scrapy has lot of dependencies like libxml2 and it also needs python-dev tools. If I had access to 'sudo apt-get ...' this would be easy but I dont'. I can only use pip and easy_install.

So How do I install the python dev tool? And how do I install the dependencies? Is this even possible?

Cheers

Comment: Whitout root access you can't.

Comment: In a shared hosting you should be able to install locally into your `Users/PakoAdrianFolder`, without root access then. Do you know if that is possible? If it is, then you could do a whole local installation of the needed dependencies and then ask `virtualenv` to refer to those locally installed packages (like python-dev).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to do what I wanted to do on the GoDaddy plan I had.

Answer (score 0):

You can install all the dependencies by activating the python virtual environment first.
Step 1 :
On Linux :
`env/bin/activate`
On Windows :
`env\Scripts\activate`
Step 2:
`pip install lxml`

I just tried and it worked for me. Please find screen shot attached.

[image: Pip install in python virtual environment]

Comment: Hey,
Thanks for the reply. pip install lxml is among the things I tried but didn't work. I get hundreds of errors. Can't paste all of them but here are some:

`src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:197456: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'xmlXPathContext'`
` src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:200265: error: 'HTML_PARSE_RECOVER' undeclared (first use in this function)`
 
And hundres more.

Comment: This is right the end `Command "/home/hirrredadmin/venv/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-caYBhV/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getat                   tr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-HA_3SJ-record/install-record                   .txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/hirrredadmin/venv/include/site/python2.6/lxml" failed with error c                   ode 1 in /tmp/pip-build-caYBhV/lxml`

Answer (score 0):

I had some of the same issues. I found [this](http://lxml.de/installation.html) and modified to `pip3.7 install lxml==3.4.2`. I was able to install successfully.

Comment: stranac pointed out in another post that async and await are keywords in 3.7, so if your are able to get scrapy installed and target this version you will get syntax errors. I created a virtualenv targeting 2.7 and had no issues with install and tested bench and shell with no issues.